# django stripe create charge

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

When i call this method.

```
charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=request.POST.get('amount', ''),
                currency=request.POST.get('currency', ''),
                source=request.POST.get('source', ''),
                idempotency_key=request.POST.get('idempotency_key', ''), # https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests
                description=request.POST.get('description', ''),
                statement_descriptor=request.POST.get('statement_descriptor', ''),
        
            )
```

It create success a payment what i checked in dashboard.

I am using test API, i see anyone can create payment without submitting their card number. why? is it secure? Can you please tell me what does these success means? how can i charge by card and it should show success in stripe dashboard?

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did provide a payment method:

```
source=request.POST.get('source', ''),
```

A Source is a Stripe object representing a payment method (probably a card number in this instance).

As to whether it's secure, that's a question only you can answer as you have all the context of this code and how it is accessed.

Looking at your code however you are creating a Charge with all the details obtained from the POST request. This is potentially insecure as you're basically giving free access to the Stripe API with your keys. Consider calculating the `amount` server side, to avoid giving your users free reign on how much they are charged.